# Set value of text a random number a combination of character and integer?

Tags: ruby, random, ruby-on-rails-4, textbox

Here is the code for the random number combining `integer` and `character`

```
<%=(0...4).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join %> <%=rand(1..2000)%>
```

**Gives output like:**

```
tqzu 1664
```

But when i put this into textbox like;

```
<input type = "text" value=<%=(0...4).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join %><%=rand(1..2000)%>  />
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ztgg
```

**Question:-**

`how to get the value of random number into textbox with the combination of char and integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form place code like this

```
<%=@rand_value = (0...4).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join.to_s + rand(1..2000).to_s %>
<%= f.text_field :text, :value => @rand_value %>
```

or you can use text_field_tag as below:

```
<%= text_field_tag "text", @rand_value %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It only processes the first part. If you place your code in a helper you can call the helper method within your view and you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your code into `"`:

```
<input type = "text" value="<%=(0...4).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join %> <%=rand(1..2000)%>" />
```

or better:

```
# in helper
def code
  [(0...4).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join,
   rand(1..2000)].join(' ')
end

# in view
<%= tag :input, :value => code %>
```